# scrapy for several websites

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl some websites. In my project, every spider has same code but start_urls, domain and  name.(It' means that my spider is just a general spider, I use it to crawl every websites.) 
My aims :

1. Just use one spider(Since every spider has same code), and  set the start_urls, domain and name dynamicly（Maybe I can get these info from database)
2. Run spider and make it crawl several websites at  the same time
3. Record the log for every website, for example:  website: ' www.hhhh.com'  It should has a log file named 'hhhh_log'

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: You can run the spider from another script using `subprocess` module and give the param in arguments. But, it'll be too broad to answer all your aims. you should be more specific.

Comment: You could try to use [spider arguments](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments). Maybe something like `website=X` and then you could program some logic into your spider which does the database lookup dependant on X.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Personally I'd create a deploy script that will build all my spiders before the scheduled crawls. It might not be the best solution, but it's flexible enough and you have to do a scrapy deploy anyway (usually).

Comment: @todinov deploy script?ha...more particular？how to do it?(in fact, I'm new to python and scrapy...)

Comment: @Bearin Well, you can just load the template spider content, read from the DB, iterate over the results and replace the start_urls, etc. Then write each modified spider to a file in the spiders directory of your project. I guess there are more elegant solutions, but this should work. I suggest you try it and write if you have any  problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197798/is-scrapy-able-to-crawl-any-type-of-websites/